# Loading context in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web.xml

What is the difference between loading context in context param and loading it in init-param of Dispatcher Servlet.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

vs

```
<init-param>    
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>    
        <param-value> /WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml </param-value>    
  </init-param>
```

What i understood is context-param is loaded by context listener and should only contain middle tier beans. Where as Dispatcher Servlet  in its init method should load web tier beans. Is this understanding correct? Why do we load 2 things seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<context-param>
```

- Is written outside `<Servlet>` tag and is inside `<webapp>` tag.
- The values decalred will be available to the whole application
- Any servlet in the application (declared in the web.xml) can access the values
- So we use this when we want to share the the same set of values across the servlet in the application such as Data base configuration details.
- You can use `public String getInitParameter(String name)` method of `ServletContext` interface to get value.
- `getServletContext()` method of ServletConfig interface returns the object of ServletContext.
- `getServletContext()` method of GenericServlet class returns the object of ServletContext.
- Example 1 : `ServletContext application=getServletConfig().getServletContext();`
- Example 2 :  `ServletContext application=getServletContext();`

`<init-param>                                                                  .`

- Is written inside `<Servlet>` tag.
- The values declared will be available only to the servlet.
- You can use `public String getInitParameter(String name)` method of `ServletConfig` interface to get value.
- `getServletConfig()` method of Servlet interface returns the object of ServletConfig.
- Example : `ServletConfig config=getServletConfig();`

Answer (score 1):

In the context-param "contextConfigLocation" you should include your application contexts, as you have already said middle tier beans, like: services, datasource...

The Spring DispatcherServlet will look for config files in WEB-INF/servletName-servlet.xml. Using the init-param you can change this default behaviour. The servlets contexts (web contexts) are isolated but might hold the application contexts as parent. You can use both or one of them independently.